# Получение информации из xml файла в textbox С#

Tags: c#

У меня появилась проблема в процессе программирования. Не могу понять как корректней вывести информацию в `textbox` из XML файла? Вот сам код:

```
private void GetWeather()
{
    string query = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22chisinau%2C%20md%22)&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
    XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
    wData.Load(query);

    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");

    XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("//channel");
    XmlNode itemNode = channel.SelectSingleNode("item");
    XmlNodeList forecastNodes = itemNode.SelectNodes("yweather:forecast", manager);

    string city = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:location", manager).Attributes["city"].Value;
    string humidity = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:atmosphere", manager).Attributes["humidity"].Value;
    string windSpeed = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:wind", manager).Attributes["speed"].Value;

    string[] temperature = new string[forecastNodes.Count+1];
    string[] conditionText = new string[forecastNodes.Count+1];

    temperature[0] = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["temp"].Value;
    conditionText[0] = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;
    for (int i=0; i<forecastNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        temperature[i+1] = forecastNodes[i].Attributes["low"].Value;
        conditionText[i+1] = forecastNodes[i].Attributes["text"].Value;
    }
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: а пример `XML` файла?

Comment: Вот ссылка на этот XML [ссылка](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22chisinau%2C%20md%22)&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)